How to set a path prefix for a gRPC service running alongside a REST API in the same Docker container?
I have a server hosted at server.com where multiple systems run with different path prefixes, like server.com/abc and server.com/def. For my specific application, I need the prefix server.com/reports.
This application is built in Go and has two services:
A REST API accessible at server.com/reports/api running on port 80.
A gRPC service that I would like to make accessible at either server.com/reports/grpc or mapped to port 5578.
Both services run in the same Docker container. Here’s how I start the gRPC service:
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("0.0.0.0:%s", port))
    grpc_server := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterReportServer(grpc_server, newServer())
    grpc_server.Serve(lis)

My Dockerfile looks like this, a part of it:
FROM golang:1.22-alpine as build

WORKDIR /go/src/

COPY . .

RUN go mod download
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o /go/bin/kreports main.go
RUN apk add --no-cache tzdata

FROM scratch

COPY --from=build /go/bin/kreports /go/bin/kreports
COPY --from=build /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
COPY --from=build /go/src/templates /templates

EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 5578

ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/kreports"]


And my .proto file looks like this:
syntax = "proto3";

package proto_files;

option go_package = "./;proto_files";

service Report {
    rpc SendPetitionReport(ReportPetitionRequest) returns (ReportPetitionResponse) {}
    rpc SendStatusReport(StatusRequest) returns (stream StatusResponse) {}
}


My question is:
Can I configure the gRPC service path prefix (/reports/grpc) directly in the Go code?
Or do I need to use an external tool like NGINX or Docker Compose for reverse proxy configuration?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

gRPC (uses HTTP/2) which doesn't support path prefixes as you use with HTTP/1. It's possible that there are implementations that would support the use of paths somehow but, even if you were able to proxy a path, none of the standard clients would be able to invoke the {host}:{port}/{prefix} path. You may also create technical debt for yourself which would incur increasing costs. If I were you, I'd consider either proxying HTTP/REST and gRPC traffic on a single port or (preferably) using distinct ports for HTTP/REST and for gRPC traffic.

gRPC supports serving multiple services (each with multiple methods) from a single host:port.

I use NGINX for that. server.com runs only nginx that does TLS operations and then routes paths to the actual servers in the internal network. Using Nginx reverse proxy you can route /reports to whatever port/path you need.

I think you need to use a reverse proxy such as Nginx for that.
Personally, I prefer Traefik over Nginx as it can automatically handle tls certificates for you, so you do not need a seperate service for that. (I've also found Traefik to work better in Kubernetes environments, so you can apply your knowledge in both cases; not relevant if you're only using Docker however)
A reverse proxy allows you to decouple concern for things like path prefixes from your application and the deployment environment.
I recommend creating a routing rule for your prefix and then routing that request via a stripprefix middleware to your service. The middleware removes the path prefix from the HTTP request before it gets to your service, so it can correctly match the request path again.
